# Make a frame, cause modifier frame fails

Tags: wireframe

Is there a way to make the following possible:

I want to cancel the part where i put the blue cross and have a frame starting from where i outlined it with red till the edge. It needs to be a mirror frame.

I have tried the wireframe modifier, but that created a very different shape than i desire as you can see on the other picture. Is there a way for this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you [edit] your question with more clear explanation of the desired result? "...cancel the part where i put the blue cross...", "..frame starting from where i outlined it.." How does selecting two faces where the blue lines are, insetting them with `I` and deleting selected faces after inset differs from your desired result?

Comment: If i select the face of the blue cross, which is divided in 2 pieces and click 'I', it moves the two parts separately which created a frame part in the middle that i dont want. Is there a way to get rid of those lines in the middle? I cant just delete the lines in anyway, cause it messes up the shape of my mesh.

I also didnt know about the 'I' option, thats why i am hear to ask and learn.

Comment: Ok i have just cut my mesh in half and duplicate it, then used mirror modifier again, to get rid of the seam in the middle, cause i made a mistake with the previous mirror modifier and settings. Then i did your method and it looks better now, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

draw the shape you want out in  Photoshop or paint then go into blender and try to box model the shape, the wire frame modifier will just turn your edges into shapes.

Comment: Ok i have just drawn a line with vertices and used the frame modifier, but it creates a flat frame. i prefer it to be a bit more round. Not actualy round, but at least some 3D look.

Comment: @fursims you could try the bevel modifier

Answer (score 0):

So there is your base model that is mirrored by the X axis.
[image: Your tombstone model thing]

Now copy that model and remove the mirror modifier from the copy so that you're only left with half of it like this:
[image]

Now shrink the copy by all axis with `S` so it covers the space you want to remove and then expand the Y axis of the model with `S + Y`. You should now have something that looks like that:
[image]

Now go to the base model(the mirrored one) and add a boolean modifier above the mirror modifier, choose the copy of the model as the object to do the operation on(cube 3 in my case).
[image]

Now either apply the boolean modifier and remove the copy(cube 3 in my case) or just hide the copy and you should be left with just the frame of the base model:
[image]